# Waiting state of a service worker.

Tags: javascript, browser, service-worker

There are three states in which a service worker can be in its life time.

The first state is installed state meaning when the service worker is finished installing.

The third state is active state meaning the service worker can now interfere the request from the loading page that is in the scope of a service worker.

There is another state called the waiting state that means that the service worker is installed but is waiting because there is some other service worker that's currently active.

Most of the places I looked has a explanation that goes something like this, " The new service worker waits because to make sure only 1 version of your website runs at a given time". The explanation sounds simple but I actually didn't get the reason and what does "only 1 version at a time" means.

It would be really helpful if someone can explain the problem in simple terms.

Answer (score 2):

This question confuses me often too, so I'll try to make up some examples and hopefully clarify for us both.

### Example 1

Lets say you have version 1 of your site with a version 1 service worker:

- Your site requests pictures of cats
- Your service worker intercepts pictures of cats and replaces them with pictures of dogs

Then you update your service worker to v2:

- now your SW intercepts pictures of cats and replaces them with pictures of bunnies

If a user with the v1 SW installed visits the site now, and the v2 service worker is set to activate immediately, there is a race:

- If the v2 SW is fetched, installed, and activated before an image request is made (maybe its requested on user input or lazy loaded or something slow), then the cat image will be replaced with a bunny
- But if a cat image is requested before the v2 SW activates, the image will be replaced with a dog

So if this was something more significant than just animal pictures then your site could conceivably break for some users depending on timing.

[That example](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase) is from Jake Archibald (I probably butchered it) and he has a demo app linked in there, but I don't think the article itself explains the risks specifically. But the idea is that

> "skipWaiting() means that your new service worker is likely
>   controlling pages that were loaded with an older version. This means
>   some of your page's fetches will have been handled by your old service
>   worker, but your new service worker will be handling subsequent
>   fetches."

Where skipWaiting is the same as immediate activation. To continue the idea of subsequent page loads...

### Example 2

Again let's say you have version 1 of your site with a version 1 service worker:

- Your backend endpoints return JSON for dynamic content
- The service worker serves index.html with a cache-first strategy
- The service worker handles templating in your site (so when some JSON is fetched from an endpoint, the service worker makes HTML from that & returns the ready-to-insert HTML to the page - [here is an example of that](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#serviceworker-side-templating))

But then you decide to just do templating the the page itself because that makes more sense for browsers that don't support service worker. You implement version 2 of your site and version 2 of your service worker:

- The service worker now returns JSON directly (no templating in the SW)
- The page expects JSON and renders templates there.

Now if a user refreshes thier app after you've released v2 (assuming they had visited during v1):

- their active v1 service worker is going to serve your v1 index.html from the cache, which expects HTML to be returned on requests.
- the v2 service worker is going to install

If the v2 service worker activated right now, they would have a v1 index.html page that expects templated HTML from requests, but your new v2 service worker is going to be returning JSON.

I could be wrong here, so I'm open to other suggestions but I thought I'd take a stab at it. Hope that helps?